# Is there a php script that will ssh into the main server and run a shell script with passed parameters?

Tags: php, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I have a form page with 4 text fields on an intranet webpage, when I hit submit on the page I want it to pass the fields as parameters to a shell script on the remote server.

Example:
Computer A accessing a web page hosted on Computer B
Computer A enter 1 2 3 4 clicks submit on page

I now want Computer B to run 'sh Test.sh 1 2 3 4'
I tried using shell_exec and I cant seem to get it to work

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can write a bash script and trigger it with exec but I'm not 100%

Comment: Computer A will have PHP page..
Computer B will have CGI script on webserver..

Now you can execute CGI Script and take param1 param2 param3 & param4 as GET Query String and can run the script or can pass the arguments on Script at any location of Computer B